# How to access an array that is defined in the file scope from a function in the same file in PHP?

Tags: php, scope

I'm writing a blacklist word checker. I've named the script as `blacklist_check.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php
$black_list = [
  'ass',
  'anus',
  /* many others that i skipped here */
];

function is_black_listed ($word) {
  return in_array($word, $black_list);
}
?>
```

However when I use the `is_black_listed` function, I always get `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`.

Should I put the `$black_list` array inside of `is_black_listed` function? I don't want to do it, as the array would always get created when I call the function, instead of it being just one time when I require (or include) the script!

Should I use `global $black_list` inside of `is_black_listed` function?

Help me out with the best practice to solve this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a global variable, they're pretty hard to maintain and make your code less readable. Instead, just pass the array to the function:

```
function is_black_listed ($word, $black_list)
```

Then call it with:

```
is_black_listed( "bad words!", $black_list);
```

Better yet, create a class to do this, and create the array as a member variable:

```
class WordFilter {
    private $black_list = [ ... ];

    function __construct( $words = array()) {
        // Optionally add dynamic words to the list
        foreach( $words as $word) 
            $black_list[] = $word;
    }

    function is_black_listed( $word) {
        return in_array( $word, $this->black_list);
    }
}

$filter = new WordFilter( array( 'potty', 'mouth'));
$filter->is_black_listed( "bad");
```

Comment: This doesn't feel right from the data hiding perspective. If I ever rename `$black_list` in the file, then suddenly I've to rename it *everywhere* where I used the `is_black_listed` function.

Comment: Then use a class like I added :)

Comment: I like the class approach. I love the data encapsulation!

Comment: There are other things you can do with this class that make it pretty convenient - Create a white list and encapsulate the whole thing within the class, make the member vars and functions static so you don't need an instance of the class to check against the filters, dynamically add / remove words to the black / white list.